# Use Bower in existing (non-bower) project

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bower

I would like to add bower to my existing project. But the key thing is that it is huge. I've got almost 30-40 external libraries that has been installed previously without Bower. I'd like to manage them now by Bower. Is there any way to do this easily? I've tried `bower init` and `bower install` but it founds only 3 libraries.

My directory tree:

```
/lib
    /angular
        angular.js
        angular-animate.js
        angular-cookies.js
        ...
    /c3
        c3.js
        ...
    /d3
        d3.v3.js
        ...
    ...
```

My result after `bower init` in `bower.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "toastr": "~2.0.3",
    "angular-ui-grid": "3.0.6"
}
```

Comment: if you know the github repo you can add it using "user/repo" and also you can check the bower json file for the package name if it has one. I don't think there is a good way to add existing libraries without getting the name first. Also realize that bower will install dependencies for you.

Comment: What heavyhorse said. Also you may want to consider npm; even the creator of Bower has conceded that long-term npm is going to succeed Bower for the frontend. You can search for packages on both Bower and npm's respective websites.

Comment: Ohh... As I thought it won't be fast and easy... Anyway, thanks for you help!